# VNC over lightdm results in blank screen

Tags: gnome, configuration, lightdm, vnc, xserver

I'm trying to set up VNC over lightdm so multiple users may log in to the server and have their own session each. I'm using TightVNC Viewer from a Windows machine to connect to the Ubuntu virtual machine (VMware on a server). The unity greeter is shown, I can enter my credentials, but then the desktop would just not load, all I get is a blank screen with a wallpaper. I also tried the lightdm-gtk-greeter, with the same result.

Here's my /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf:

```
[SeatDefaults]
allow-guest=false
greeter-hide-users=true
greeter-show-manual-login=true
autologin-guest=false
# More sessions at /usr/share/xsessions/
user-session=gnome-fallback
# More greeters at /usr/share/xgreeters/
# greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
greeter-session=unity-greeter
[XDMCPServer]
enabled=true
port=177
[VNCServer]
enabled=true
command=/usr/bin/Xvnc -rfbauth /etc/vncpasswd
port=5900
width=1280
height=1024
depth=24
```

Note the user-session: I'm trying to log into a gnome-fallback session. The unity-greeter indeed has Gnome preselected. I tried the other entries as well (e.g. Gnome Classic), with the same result.

Errors are logged in ~/.xsession-errors:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: gpg-agent post-stop process (4335) killed by TERM signal
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd respawning too fast, stopped
init: unity-settings-daemon main process (4382) terminated with status 1
init: unity-settings-daemon main process ended, respawning
init: gnome-session (Unity) main process (4391) terminated with status 1
init: unity-settings-daemon main process (4573) killed by TERM signal
init: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
```

Messages in /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log immediately after entering the credentials in the greeter:

```
[+971.31s] DEBUG: Session pid=5164: Continue authentication
[+971.92s] DEBUG: Session pid=5220: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+971.92s] DEBUG: Session pid=5164: Authenticate result for user pamberg: Success
[+971.92s] DEBUG: Session pid=5164: User pamberg authorized
[+971.93s] DEBUG: Session pid=5164: Greeter requests default session
[+971.93s] DEBUG: Seat: Stopping greeter; display server will be re-used for user session
[+971.93s] DEBUG: Session pid=5164: Sending SIGTERM
[+971.95s] DEBUG: Session pid=5164: Exited with return value 0
[+971.95s] DEBUG: Seat: Session stopped
[+971.95s] DEBUG: Seat: Greeter stopped, running session
[+971.95s] DEBUG: Registering session with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
[+971.99s] DEBUG: Session pid=5220: Not setting XDG_VTNR
[+972.00s] DEBUG: Session pid=5220: Running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-session /usr/lib/gnome-panel/gnome-session-flashback
[+972.00s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/pamberg
[+972.00s] DEBUG: Session pid=5220: Logging to .xsession-errors
[+972.08s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c13
[+972.12s] WARNING: Error activating login1 session: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: Operation not supported
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/1420558. In short, LightDM's AppArmor policy isn't (as of Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS) taking VNC into account.

Try removing `/etc/apparmor.d/lightdm-guest-session`.