# VNC login to Ubuntu Server 18.04.5LTS running Lightdm presents a blank desktop

Tags: server, lightdm, remote-desktop, vnc

Running a headless Ubuntu Server (...server) 18.04.5 LTS setup. Installed the lightdm package and x11vnc.

When I connect with vnc viewer, all goes smoothy - vnc credentials accepted, and I am presented with your standard ubuntu login screen (you can see the tool bar at the top, and the drop-downs work etc.)

[Before logging into ubuntu through VNCviewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcQ5O.png)

But then I login (which is accepted) and I get the blank desktop wallpaper - no functionality - no cursor, icons, toolbars etc. Keyboard shortcuts don't bring anything up either.

[after logging into ubuntu through VNCviewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mtWV.png)

NB: I've already been about the webernets and have seen (on here as well) others with similar problem, but their solutions have not worked for me.
e.g.

- [Ubuntu 19.04 VNC stuck after login screen of LightDM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152772/ubuntu-19-04-vnc-stuck-after-login-screen-of-lightdm)
- [blank screen with vnc server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127466/blank-screen-with-vnc-server)
- [VNC over lightdm results in blank screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571263/vnc-over-lightdm-results-in-blank-screen)

Any many others. Happy to provide any info your need on various config files etc - just ask (not sure what's needed upfront, so don't want to clutter the post).